# Jupyter No module named graphviz after successful installation

Tags: python-2.7, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I installed graphviz by

```
conda install python-graphviz
```

after successful installation, when run

```
import graphviz
```

I got " ImportError: No module named graphviz" on jupyter notebook/python2.7.

But if run it in cmd like:

```
Python 2.7.15 |Anaconda, Inc |...
>>>import graphviz
>>>
```

it works well.

Why the "import graphviz" doesn't work in jupyter but work in cmd?
How to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You also need the Python interface for Graphviz

```
conda install -c conda-forge python-graphviz
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your jupyter notebook is using the same version of python as your terminal is seeing. So in jupyter notebook,

`import sys`

`print(sys.version)`

and do the same in python in your terminal. If they do not match, then load in the terminal version of python into your jupyter notebook:

`conda install nb_conda_kernels`

`conda install ipykernel`

and in the notebook, select it with kernel -> change kernel